# "null is not an object" error when Framework7 inserts new page to DOM

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I am learning Framework7,

when i insert a new page named"about" using ajax:

```
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="content-block">
    <p id="myID">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i wish execute a javascript function using getElementById("myID") after the page is initialized, using:

```
myApp.onPageInit('about', function (page) {

document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!"; 

})
```

but i have the "null is not an object" error, because the element with the id= "myID" is not find in the DOM.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its the case from your code, but if you're using AJAX then you are most likely attempting to reference the ID before it is actually in the DOM. You need to setup a promise or use a `.done()` so your code knows when the asynchronous function has finished.

Comment: Thanks, very much